# how I do streaming with raspberry by rtp?

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam

I want to cast my webcam by rtp with raspberry pi.

I've tried this:

ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -v verbose -r 5 -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 –f rtp rtp://192.168.1.205:5005/webcam.ffm

but it fails to play in VLC.

how I can do it?

thanks

Comment: any error messages on either side?

Comment: Would this be on-topic for http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: no, but when I play it with VLC, it fails.

Comment: Moreover, I've tried this: sudo ffmpeg -v verbose -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj440p -i /dev/video0 -vcodec mjpeg -an -pix_fmt yuvj440p -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.27:5004